# What does it mean having 1 as best k parameter in K-NN?

Tags: machine-learning, python, scikit-learn, hyperparameter, k-nearest-neighbour

I'm working with a large dataset (761 rows and about 57k-60k features) and after doing a feature selection to select the best 10 features I'm using different ML algorithms to classify some cases. In the case of the K-NN I performed a hyperparameter tunning using GridSearchCV from sklearn and after many tests this returns 1 as the best value for k.

I tried with the RandomizedSearch too and increasing *n_iter* parameter makes it to eventually return 1 aswell as the best value for k.

Does this mean something? It seems strange to me having this value as the best for k. Could it be overfitting maybe?

Thanks!

Comment: Does your dataset contain exact duplicate patterns (after feature selection)? Also how is the feature selection performed?

Comment: @DikranMarsupial What do you exactly mean with duplicate patterns? My dataset contains 761 cases of both breast cancer and ovarian cancer patient cases and each column represents the gene expession level of a concrete gene. First I standardise the data, then remove 0-variance features and then perform a feature selection with SelectKBest from sklearn selecting the best 10 features. After this I use a LogisticRegressor model to get the best 5 out of the best 10 (using the beta coefficients).

Comment: @Julien I mean patterns where the attribute values are the same as the attribute values of another pattern.  In that case 1-nn performs well if there are a lot of duplicate patterns.  How does SelectKBest work?  If you are applying it to the whole dataset and then using cross-validation to tune the hyper-parameters, you have a dataleak as the test data for hyper-parameter selection has already been used to select the features.  I've worked on microarray data, LASSO/L1 regularisation is likely to be a better approach.

Comment: Try doing the feature selection independently in each fold of the cross-validation procedure used to tune the hyper-parameters.  With cross-validation it is best viewed as a means of estimating the performance of a *method* for generating a model, rather than the model itself, so you need to cross-validate *all* parts of the method, including standardisation and feature selection.

Comment: @DikranMarsupial First I split the data into training and test, then fit the scaler and the feature selector only with the training data and then transform both training and test data. Seems like I do have some duplicates, but the thing is that when using different models like naive bayes, decision tree or svm i get almost the same results. All around 97-100%

Comment: @DikranMarsupial I checked the duplicates after the feature selection using `X_train_scaled.duplicated(subset=None, keep=False)` and it seems that there are not duplicates

Comment: If the test set isn't used for model or feature selection, then I suspect you are O.K. and it is just a relatively easy classification problem.  I tend to repeat the whole experiment several times with different initial test-training splits in order to get some idea of the variation in the performance estimate due to that partitioning.  It is possible to have bad  or good luck with that, especially for very small datasets.

Comment: @DikranMarsupial Fine, I'll try anyways splitting the data differently to see how it behaves. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing "bad" about $k=1$. It's a hyperparameter to tune, so different values would work for different problems. If you did your hyperparameter tuning correctly, i.e. there are no data leaks in cross-validation, then it's not overfitting because the parameter was validated on external data. If you worry about overfitting, use the held-out test set to verify the final solution, if it is overfitted then the model would perform poorly on the test set.

If $k=1$ is the best, this may simply mean that your data can be easily explained by a fixed set of "typical cases" that you just need to memorize for making predictions. With higher values of $k$ you would average over multiple examples to reduce noise, maybe here it unnecessarily "blurs" the predictions and noise is not an issue. Of course, those are just guesses, you would need to conduct an in-depth exploratory analysis of the predictions to answer the "why" question.

Comment: Right, overfitting would lead to poor performance on test set but I got 100% accuracy on both training and test sets, is this common?

Comment: @Julen maybe your problem is just simple to solve? Make sure there is no data leak, bugs in the code, etc if that is not the case, yes it is possible to have a perfect fit in some cases. If still in doubt, gather more "realistic" examples for testing and see if the performance still holds.

Comment: "i.e. there are no data leaks in cross-validation, then it's not overfitting because the parameter was validated on external data." this is not strictly speaking true because it is possible to over-fit the cross-validation statistic in tuning the hyper-parameters.  This isn't usually an issue if there are few hyper-parameters, but if other hyper-parameters were being tuned (which is where we would normally use RandomizedSearch) is may be a consideration.

Comment: @Tim Fine, I'll try gathering more data and seeing how it behaves with it. Thanks!

Comment: @DikranMarsupial ok, you can overfit to test set if you try hard enough.

Comment: @Tim, in this case I think the issue is a data leak caused by performing feature selection first and then tuning $k$ (if cross-validation had already been used for that, then it may have already been overfitted).

Comment: @DikranMarsupial I don't see it like this, but mentioned in my answer that this needs to be double checked by OP before concluding that the results are valid.